# Do I need to use "a" in "a few deep breaths"?

Tags: sentence-construction, articles, american-english

I wrote this line in a short story.

> I took few deep breaths.

But one person commented that it is wrong and it should be

> I took **a** few deep breaths.

Now I am confused. Which one is correct?
Both look correct to me. When should I use the first one or the second one?

Comment: Both can be correct, but I suspect you want the second one.

Comment: A few deep breaths =  breathed in, out, in, out, in out deeply.  Few deep breaths = most were shallow, possibly gasps:  "gasping for breath".

Comment: Read up on "few" vs. "a few".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*A few* is a positive term that indicates a small number. When we use it we are asserting the positive existence of a small number of something.

*Few* is a negative word. It has a negative meaning. It means *not many*. If we use *few*, we are stressing there were not many, when perhaps people thought there were.

If someone offers you a job and you ask:

- Are there any opportunities for promotion?

Then if they say:

- There are a few opportunities for promotion.

This means that the speaker thinks that you may have a chance to get promoted. However, if they say:

- There are few opportunities for promotion.

Then this means that they are stressing that there are not many opportunities. They probably think it is unlikely you will ever get a promotion.

We can show that *a few* is a positive term and *few* is a negative term by putting a question tag onto each sentence. Usually, if a sentence is positive, it will have a negative question tag. If a sentence is negative it will have a positive question tag:

- There **are** opportunities for promotion, **aren't there**?
- There **are** a few opportunities for promotion, **aren't there**?
- There **aren't** opportunities for promotion, **are there**?
- There **are few** opportunities for promotion, **are there**?

From the examples above we can see, that *a few* does not change the polarity of the sentence. The sentence remains positive. In contrast *few* makes the sentence negative.

**The Original Poster's question**

The Original Poster probably wants to say:

- I took a few deep breaths

This is because they just want to explain that they took a small number of deep breaths. They probably didn't want to say that they *didn't* take many breaths. There is no reason to emphasise *NOT MANY* in this situation.

*Hope this is helpful!*

Comment: "A few is a positive term that indicates a small number. When we use it we are asserting the positive existence of a small number of something." So how do you interpret "There's no such thing as a few cockroaches."?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast That means in a positive sentence! That sentence means the same thing as *There is no such thing as a small number of cockroaches!* :)

Comment: But the sentence asserts that the things do NOT exist.